# Using array.some()

Tags: javascript

I am building an e-commerce application. When add to cart route point(/cart/add/: id) is hit, I check for a condition that if the product already exists in cart or not using array.some()

```
 var hi = req.session.user.cart.some(function(element,index,array){

            return element.productId === req.params.id ;
        })

        console.log("hi' value "+hi);
        if(hi === true){
            var myResponse = responseGenerator.generate(false,"I already 
             exists",200,false);
               res.send(myResponse);
        }
        else{
           //proceed to next step and push the product to cart array
        }
```

All goes well and prints the message "I already exist" until I remove the product from cart. After removing the product from the cart, if I hit the add to cart route again, it prints the above message instead of adding the product to cart. I'm not sure whether I am using the array.some() correctly

my remove from cart code

```
  cartRouter.post('/delete/:id',auth.checkLogin,function(req,res){

    //FIND USER AND PULL/REMOVE PRODUCT FROM CART 

    userModel.update({"_id":req.session.user._id},{$pull:{cart:
                {"productId":req.params.id}}},function(err,user){
        if(err){
                var myResponse = 
                 responseGenerator.generate(true,err,500,null);
                res.send(myResponse);
        }
        else{
                ourInfo.productDel = true;

                var myResponse = responseGenerator.generate(false,"Deleted 
                   successfully",200,ourInfo);
                res.send(myResponse);
         }
     })


 });
```

I am sure that the products are getting removed from the cart as their length is 0. But somehow I am not able to add the same product after removing from cart.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't clearing it out of the session array

Comment: Exactly, it looks to me like the delete endpoint is removing the item from the cart within mongoDB but not from the session variable req.session.user.cart. You also need to remove the product from that array. The database and session are not magically synced (unfortunately).

Comment: The problem was with the session. Instead of using .some() on session.cart, I performed a DB operation to get a user and, to the user.cart field, I ran the .some() method. Now resolved!. Thanks, guys.